# Passing a class as a variable - School example - Java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble getting my head around passing classes as variables, for example - I am thinking of a school and how one could implement a simple system to keep track of things such as

- Students
- Teachers
- Subjects

Such that the following are true:

- a Student **takes a** Subject
- a Teacher **teaches a** Subject
- a Subject **has both** Students **and** Teachers

A basic example of each class would be as follows:

**Student.java**

```
private String name;
private int age;
private Subject subject;
private String school; // Can implement another class of School later

public Student(int id, String name, int age, String school, String course) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.school = school;
    this.course = subject;
}
```

**Teacher.java**

```
private String name;
private Subject subjectTaught;
private Date taughtSince; // Date is another thing that perplexes me, but that can be saved for another time
private int holidaysRemaining;

public Teacher(int id, String name, Subject subjectTaught, String taughtSince, int holidaysRemaining) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.subjectTaught = subjectTaught;
    this.taughtSince = taughtSince;
    this.holidaysRemaining = holidaysRemaining;
}
```

**Subject**

```
String name;
int length;
Teacher teacher;
Student student;

public Subject(int id, String name, int length, Teacher teacher, Student student) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.length = length;
    this.teacher = teacher;
    this.student = student;
}
```

I understand that I can implement an ArrayList or a HashMap within Subject to keep track of which students are taking which subjects etc.

I am just a little lost when it comes to actually getting code down to make things happen...

The eventual outcome would be to have some sort of 'inventory management system' for CRUD operations, adding students and teachers to subjects etc.

Any guidance would be great!

Comment: So you want another Object that stores a Subject which has a Student & Teacher?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question title. Is 'class' a 'class' as in a school class or a class as in a Java [`class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Comment: I have amended my question to have 'subjects' rather than 'classes' @Dinh

Comment: @M.leRutte - Updated info - It's like a content management system I'm wanting

Comment: "_a Student takes a Subject_" that's a lucky student, I used to takes multiples _Subject_. Same for your teachers.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and think about that. "Giving some guidance" is a too broad question here.

Comment: The way you have phrased your question will give you results of varying quality I'm afraid, with lots of opinions on `ArrayLists` vs `HashMaps` vs `arrays`. If I look at the answers below, I would give yet another different solution.

btw. don't store `age` as an int, use a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), which replaces `Date`. Follow the Oracle [trail on date and time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) for more info.

Comment: @M.leRutte - I was hoping for a flurry of different answers. I'm still learning this trade, so the more I see - the more I'll learn :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Student.java` and `Teacher.java` should have `Subject[] subjects` instead of `Subject subject`. As every Student as well as Teacher  is linked with a lot of Subjects rather than just one.

Comment: That makes sense.
I was perhaps thinking the opposite way around with having an ArrayList/HashMap of students/teachers in the subjects class

Comment: That depends on the use-case of your application.
**> There will be a lot of Students.**
**> There will be a lot of Teachers but fewer than Students.**
**> There will be fewer number of Subjects.**

>> To search the Student faster, make the Student as the key in a HashMap and let Teacher and Subject be linked to the Student.
>> To search the Teacher faster, make the Teacher as the key in a HashMap and let Student and Subject be linked to the Teacher.
>> Same for the Subject.

Comment: Don't use arrays ([]) use [collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice @itch96, I will have a look at the best way I can get it to work. I'm not going to have thousands of records to begin with, only a few of each I think.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this points you to the right direction?
I am not sure if I totally understand your question please let me know if this is what you were looking for!

```
public class School {

    private String name;
    private Map<String, Subject> subjects = new HashMap<>();

    public School(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void addSubject(Subject subject) {
        subjects.add(subject.name, subject);
    }

    public Subject getSubject(String name) {
        return subjects.get(name);
    }
}

public class Subject {

    Map<String, Student> students = new HashMap<>();
    String name;
    int length;
    Teacher teacher;

    public Subject(int id, String name, int length, Teacher teacher) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.add(student.name, student);
    }

    public void getStudent(String name) {
        students.get(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is looking kind of like what I have seen in the past in other people's code. It makes sense how you have laid it out. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I'm assuming that if I would want a subject to have more than 1 teacher (not teaching simultaneously of course, don't get carried away), that I would implement a second HashMap here too??

Comment: Exactly, you would add another Map for that

Comment: If I were implementing my School.java to have Maps for Teachers, Students and Subjects, but also my Subject.java also has Maps for Teachers and Students... Could I hold that in a BaseEntity.java class and extend them into these classes such that they will hold exactly the same information across the board? I imagine I would have to make it static also.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't recommend an `ArrayList` in this instance because the same object can be present several times in a `List`. You could use a `HashSet`, in which case you would need to implement `hashCode` and `equals` in your Student and Teacher classes. You could also use a `TreeSet` if you implement a `Comparator<Student>` and a `Comparator<Teacher>`. Assuming that an object is identified by it's id field, you can also use a `HashMap`:

```
class Subject {
    String name;
    int length;
    private final Map<Integer,Teacher> teachers = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Integer,Student> students = new HashMap<>();

    public Subject(int id, String name, int length) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public void addTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        teachers.put(teacher.getId(), teacher);
    }

    public void removeTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        teachers.remove(teacher.getId());
    }

    public Teacher[] getTeachers() {
        return teachers.values().toArray(new Teacher[teachers.size()]);
    }

    // ... same for students
}
```

Comment: @Dinh OK, I was mislead by the sentence "a Subject has both Students and Teachers". But in that case you only need a map for students.

Comment: What is the use of a `HashMap` with an `Integer` key? A sneaky way to provide uniqueness? If that is important the code should throw an exception, not silently continue.

Comment: @Dinh - You never had a lesson covered by another teacher that wasn't your usual? #privilaged :-P

Thanks for the advice MauricePerry